# What equality between $a$ and $c$, and between $b$ and $d$ means in this statement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

As I know, and ordered pair can be defined in terms of sets, so equality of ordered pairs is the same as equality of sets. 
And I found such a theorem on the Wikipedia page about ordered pairs

> $(a, b) = (c, d)$ if and only if $a = c$ and $b = d$.

And my question is this, what do this equalities $$a=c$$ and $$b=d$$ mean in terms of logic and set theory ?

I know that equality can be defined as a relation, so does it mean this relation there ?

Comment: $=$ is usually taken to be part of the language and symbolizes the concept of identity. If $\phi$ is any predicate, then $a=c$ implies that $\phi(a)\leftrightarrow\phi(c)$. -- In set theory, you might be able to eliminate $=$ per $a=c:\iff \forall x(x\in a\leftrightarrow x\in c)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can we somehow repeat the folowing proof with the defintion you gave ?                                                                                "If a = c and b = d, then {{a}, {a, b}} = {{c}, {c, d}}. Thus (a, b) = (c, d)"

Comment: For example, one step of the proof will probably be to apply the "substitution rule" given by Hagen von Eitzen with $\phi(x) = (\{ a \} \in x)$ to conclude that because $\{ a \} \in \{ \{ a \}, \{ a, b \} \}$, then $\{ a \} \in \{ \{ c \}, \{ c, d \} \}$.

Comment: Ordinarily, in mathematics, two things are *equal* if they are one and the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the definition of $=$(for sets, not proper class) is(usually): $(A=B)\iff(\forall x(x\in A\iff x\in B))$

The usual definition of ordered pair is: $(a,b)\iff\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$

If you want to prove that $(a,b)=(c,d)\iff a=c\land b=d$ using the definition of equality I would suggest to first prove it using $=$ and then replace all of the $=$ with the definition.

Notice $a,b,c,d$ has to be sets with this definition, otherwise it is undefined